# Paperclip, how to exchange 2 images that have already been saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have an app that allows users to upload 5 pictures. Everything works fine in my backend, which uses Rails & Paperclip.

Now however, I'd like to add the functionality where users can change the order of their images.

For example, if someone's profile has 5 pictures and he wants to exchange the position of Picture 4 and Picture 1, how can I do that with Paperclip?

Is there an easy way to exchange images? My concern is that when Picture 4 saves details from Picture 1, Picture 1 can no longer save Picture 4 because Picture 4 is now Picture 1. (Since it runs in sequence and not simultaneously).

Currently paperclip is saving images through a URL, so soon as Picture 4 saves Picture 1 in it's place, the image has been replaced.

I'm hoping paperclip has some 'swap image' functionality built in to make my life easier...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to control image ordering would be do add another column to order the images with, e.g.:

```
rails g AddSequenceToImages sequence:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Then, anytime you display the images, you order then using that column, e.g.:

```
user.images.order(:sequence)
```

Implementing an interface to order the images would be a bit more involved, but essentially you would only need to change the `sequence` value.